# Query returning duplicate registers

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to get an index fragmentation history report but they just return with some duplicated registers.

Below you can see my history table and the query i'm using:

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[FragmentationHistory](
[IdxDatabase] [nvarchar](200) NULL,
[IdxTable] [nvarchar](200) NULL,
[IdxID] [int] NULL,
[IdxName] [nvarchar](200) NULL,
[FragmentationPercent] [real] NULL,
[InfoDate] [date] NULL,
[Enabled] [bit] NOT NULL) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Query:

```
select distinct(a.idxname), a.infodate, a.FragmentationPercent, b.InfoDate, b.FragmentationPercent from fragmentationhistory a 
inner join fragmentationhistory b
on a.IdxName = b.idxname 
where a.infodate = '20170525' and b.InfoDate = '20170530'
```

Return:

[image]

Can someone help me? How can I fix this query?

Comment: I have a routine that inserts daily on this table the fragmentation percent, can i make this report dynamic? ): HEEEEEEELP

Comment: They aren't duplicates.  The first FragmentationPercent field is different.  That suggests that you have 2 distinct records in there for the same index and same infodate.

Comment: What would you **expect** your output to be? You've given the current output, but we need **sample** data and **expected** output.

Comment: There are also other fields that might be causing this.  You never check if the IdxTable, IdxDatabase or IdxID are the same when you do the join.  Not sure if those are required to make sure you are looking at the same item on 2 different days, but it's worth looking at.

Comment: The `distinct` keyword works on a row basis, not a single column basis.

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Comment: What do you mean with "registers"? Do you mean _rows_?

Comment: Tks, you guys were right!